# U-net like architecture with VGG 16 as feature extractor - problems with concatenate layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I want to build a U-net architecture using the VGG 16 model as my encoder with pre-trained weights on Imagenet dataset. For the up-sampling I want to concatenate the output from some layers in the encoder with the decoding part. Almost like this (taken from TernausNet):
[TernausNet](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/cf2ff198ddd4f4600726fa0f2844e77c4041186b/68747470733a2f2f686162726173746f726167652e6f72672f776562742f68752f6a692f69722f68756a696972767067706637657377713838685f783761686c69772e706e67)

My model so far looks like this:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 as VGG16, preprocess_input
encode_model = VGG16(input_shape=(768,768,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
encode_model.trainable = False

from keras import models, layers

input_img = layers.Input((768,768,3), name = 'RGB_Input')

# output and start upsampling
features = encode_model(input_img)
conv_1 = layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(features)
up_conv = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_1)

# first concatenation block
concat_1 = layers.concatenate([encode_model.get_layer('block5_conv3').output, up_conv], axis=-1, name='concat_1')
conv_2 = layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(concat_1)
up_conv_2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_2)


# second concatenation block
concat_2 = layers.concatenate([up_conv_2, encode_model.get_layer('block4_conv3').output])
conv_3 = layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(concat_2)
up_conv_3 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_3)

# third concatenation block
concat_3 = layers.concatenate([up_conv_3, encode_model.get_layer('block3_conv3').output])
conv_4 = layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(concat_3)
up_conv_4 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_4)

# fourth concatenation block
concat_4 = layers.concatenate([up_conv_4, encode_model.get_layer('block2_conv2').output])
conv_5 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(concat_4)
up_conv_5 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_5)

# fifth concatenation block
concat_4 = layers.concatenate([up_conv_5, encode_model.get_layer('block1_conv2').output])
conv_6 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(concat_4)

final_model = models.Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[conv_6])
final_model.summary()
```

Later I compile and fit the model:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy  

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
    union = K.sum(y_true, axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=[1,2,3])
    return K.mean( (2. * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), 
    axis=0)

def dice_p_bce(in_gt, in_pred):
    return 1e-3*binary_crossentropy(in_gt, in_pred) - dice_coef(in_gt, 
    in_pred)

def true_positive_rate(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.flatten(y_true)*K.flatten(K.round(y_pred)))/K.sum(y_true)   

final_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3, decay=1e-6), loss=dice_p_bce, 
    metrics=[dice_coef, 'binary_accuracy', true_positive_rate])

step_count = min(MAX_TRAIN_STEPS, balanced_train_df.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE)
aug_gen = create_aug_gen(make_image_gen(balanced_train_df))
loss_history = [final_model.fit_generator(aug_gen, 
                         steps_per_epoch=step_count, 
                         epochs=NB_EPOCHS, 
                         validation_data=(valid_x, valid_y),
                         callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        workers=1)]`
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_4:0", shape=(?, 768, 768, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_4". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I read that this happens when input and output are not part of the same graph. I think that with this I am connecting both graphs:

```
input_img = layers.Input((768,768,3), name = 'RGB_Input')

# output and start upsampling
features = encode_model(input_img)
conv_1 = layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(features)
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

**I updated my answer to correspond to the edited question**

The problem I think is in this line:

```
features = encode_model(input_img)
```

`encode_model` is a keras model and you try to pass a custom input layer to it. This is certainly not required. Try the following:

```
# necessary imports
encode_model = VGG16(input_shape=(768,768,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
conv_1 = layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encode_model.output)  # need to pass the output tensor to the conv_1 layer
# define the rest of your model as you have it
```

Comment: I tried that and then i get the error: 
*'Tensor' object has no attribute 'output'*
I believe by giving the input to the model I do get the output from the VGG16 model as a tensor.
The problem is most likely in the concatenation. When I create the model with output before the first concatenation it compiles and shows all the layers just fine.

Comment: @user3578476 I changed my answer to match your new variable names. First dump the custom input and then pass the `encode_model.output` tensor to `conv_1` to connect the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already an input layer in VGG16 you don't need to define a new Input layer in this case. Just use the existing one:

```
decode_features = decode_model.output

# ...

final_model = models.Model(inputs=[decode_model.input], outputs=[conv_6])
```

**Update:** If you want to prevent the weights of VGG16 to be modified, **explicily** freeze all of its layers using `trainable` parameter:

```
for layer in decode_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Just make sure you do this before compiling the final model.

Comment: This makes sense and works. But now the VGG16 layers are trainable again. I wanted to use pre-trained weights from Imagenet for these and just train the decoding part (the concatenation and upsampling layers). Will the weights still be initialized like this?

Comment: I did this in line three. But somehow he "explodes" the whole model and makes the layers trainable again. In the overview of the layers the vgg16 does not appear in one line but all layers inside the model.
I get the following output:
`Total params: 28,504,608
Trainable params: 28,504,608
Non-trainable params: 0`

Comment: @user3578476 Would you please add the `compile` and `fit` calls to your post as well?

Comment: @user3578476 See my updated answer again. You need to explicitly freeze the layers in this case.